# Complex 3D models in WPF + XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, model, 3d

I have a project where i am supposed to replicate a monument in WPF and XAML.
As i have never used any of those I have made a simple sword to get to know xaml a bit. To make it I defined all my points and triangles by hand.
It made me realise that it will be next to impossible to do it that way for a monument if i want to have any level of detail.
I am not allowed to use any extra libraries and such.

Any advice on how i could create a model of let's say Eiffel Tower with some level of detail within reasonable amount of time?

Comment: if you are not allowed to use external libraries, then what are you asking for? an algorithm to interpret point and mesh data?

Comment: Why are you "not allowed" to use external libraries? That doesn't make any sense. I guess your only option is to export your monument file as a DXF or something and then write a little program to parse it and convert to XAML. That's what I did for my [Repic software](http://reprap.org/mediawiki/images/d/d0/Repic_Host.jpg), it only required a couple dozen lines of .NET code.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a simpeler way to create shapes other than defining all my points and triangles manually